# iphone webapp scrolling

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I am using the following code to disable all scrolling.  The goal was the give the webapp a native app feel.

`document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }`

How can I specifiy which areas to allow to scroll?

`overflow: scroll;` does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

attach your custom event listener on the desired block of htmls

```
 var listener = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); };
 node.addEventListener('touchstart', listener , false);
 node.addEventListener('touchmove', listener , false);
```

Comment: Can you clarify how to attach that?

Comment: Hate to keep asking you, but where do I put that code if I want a specific <div> to be able to scroll?

Comment: use something like var node = document.querySelector('#nodeId'); node.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){e.preventDefault();alert(1)}, false);   AND remove your document.ontouchmove handler